# What is the right way to make a branch the new master of a Git repo?

Tags: git, branch

I have a repository which went into an unwanted direction on the master branch, and I now want to copy the repository , revert the master branch back to the point where it veered of, which is a separate branch.

Will it be a matter of deleting the current master branch and renaming the branch I want to `master`?

I also want to retain all the history in the new master branch, but erase all the subsequent changes to all the other branches from the point new branch was created, as though it was always the master, as well as all other branches that do not lead to the new master branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can checkout the current branch to a new branch

```
git checkout -b <new_name>
```

#### Undo the changes

You have several ways to *undo the changes*:

#### `git revert`

- `git revert commit1 commit2 commit3 ...`
  This will reveert [undo] all the unwanted commits.

#### `git reflog`

- Find out the lats commit that you wish to keep and then check it out and create branch from this poing

  ```
  git reflog - find the sha1
  git checkout -b <commit id>
  # or
  git reset HEAD --hard <commit id>
  ```

#### `git reset`

- same as above- simply reset to the last desired commit if you know it.

---

Now you have the last desired commit in your new branch and you can decide what to do with it.

Comment: I would recommend to use the revert option. _Revert_ all changes in master you do not want, but _do not rewrite_ history. If you just delete all history of something that should not have been done, someone will do it again, as there is no longer clear indication of what should _not_ be done. Do not lie to your version control and hide mistakes, learn from them instead. Rewriting published history will always create extra work for _everyone_ working on the project.